# how do i fix Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x37aa0dc8) t

I want to call method of my DetailViewController.But they crash and show error as mention above

```
func move()
{
     let VC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDF") as! PDFViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the view controller to a navigation controller, and access its `topViewController` property.

```
let pdfVC = (storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDF") as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PDFViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)
```